# How can i Adding the shop to the homepage - Shopware 5.7.6

Tags: shopware, shopware5

shopware 5.7.6 - I want to bring the products on the shop page to the homepage, but there are only sliders or single products on the element page in the shopping world section. I want to shoot all or at least the number of products I have determined, but I don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to show all your products on the homepage, at least, that's how I understand your question. Unfortunately, I have to tell you, that there is no easy way to achieve this goal.

1. Use the given elements

You have already found the two elements you can use to show off your products. But there is no way to automatically produce a page, where all products are shown at once. You have to do that on your own, with placing the elements on your page, with one element for each product.

But you can use the category teaser to show some random products of a category. Depending on how you have structured your categories and products, it may make this task a bit easier. Maybe, but I never tried it, you can expand the category element in such a way that there is enough room for all products.

2. Use the code element

If you are familiar with webdevelopement, you could use the code element to build your own element in a kind of way. There you could pass all your products, but this will also require some work. As I said, there is no easy way to achieve your goal.

3. Build a plugin

If you are familiar with PHP, smarty, JS and jQuery, you could build a plugin, to create an own element for your pages. This may be the hardest way to achieve your goal, but it will also be the most rewarding regarding stability and functionality.

Comment: I think I used your 3rd method. By browsing the code section, I wrote a plugin that will work in the shopping world element section and using it, I listed the products in the category I wanted on the homepage. Thank you for your answer